# Configure SP2013 to connect to SQL alias Name after Installation

Tags: 2013, sql, sql-alias

I have a SP2013 farm which has 1 WFE,1 App Server and 1 SQL. While configuring,SQL Server Name was used to connect to SharePoint(in SharePoint Product configuration Wizard) and CA site has been created.

Instead of SharePoint Server name,I want to use SQL alias name for SharePoint connectivity.

How to achieve this?

Please note: I'm not allowed to change the existing database server name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Trevor already mentioned, you cannot change the SQL connection string of an existing Database without reinstalling the farm.

Maybe a [SQL-Alias with cliconfg.exe](https://nikpatel.net/2013/09/05/step-by-step-configuring-sql-alias-on-all-sharepoint-web-and-application-servers/) is an alternative for you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do so. SharePoint will always need to reference that particular SQL Server name/instance name now. In order to change it, you would have to build a new farm.

Comment: many thanks for your response. Disconnecting both App and Wfe servers from the farm and adding them again to the existing farm with the alias name won't work?

Comment: That's correct, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my WFE and App server from the farm(using Product configuration Wizard).Deleted all the existing DBs in the server.Created an Alias name for my SQL Database Server and then mapped the alias name in WFE and App server using cliconfg.exe. In App server,then ran the Product Configuration Wizard and created a new server farm and in the Database server field,I entered by Alias name.This worked for me.

Please Note: I only had my config DB and Logging DB in SQL hence I didn't bother deleting them